# Goldstein Classical Mechanics equation 8.20 clarification

Tags: classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, hamiltonian-formalism, textbook-erratum

In Goldstein (Third Edition, Page 339) the equation 8.20 is as follow:

$$ H = \dot q_ip_i - L = \dot q_ip_i-[L_0(q_i,t)+L_1(q_i,t)\dot q_k+L_2(q_i,t)\dot q_k\dot q_m].\tag{8.20}$$

Can someone explain why the second equality hold?
Moreover, $H$ is in no way a tensor, how come it has the last term indexed by $km$?

Note: by equation 2.55, the Lagrange can be decomposed as such:
$$L(q,\dot q,t)=L_0(q,t)+L_1(q,\dot q,t)+L_2(q,\dot q,t).\tag{2.55}$$
where $L_2$ is a [homogeneous](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/EulersHomogeneousFunctionTheorem.html) function of the second degree, in $\dot q$, while $L_1$ is homogeneous of the first degree in $\dot q$.

Answer (score 1):

The material surrounding eq. (8.20) in the 3rd edition is new (as compared to the 2nd edition), and filled with typos and breaks previously established notations from eqs. (1.73) & (2.55). The errors are not reported so far (February 2019) on the [errata homepage](http://astro.physics.sc.edu/Goldstein/). The errors can be fixed in various straightforward ways.

(This is another example where the 3rd edition of Goldstein is inferior to the 2nd edition, cf. [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/343456/2451) Phys.SE post.)