# What objective function is Lagrange's equation of the first kind based on?

Tags: classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, constrained-dynamics

In Lagrangian mechanics, Lagrange's equation of the first kind states that

$$ \frac{\partial L}{\partial r_k} - \frac{d}{dt}\frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot{r_k}} + \sum_{i=1}^C \lambda_i \frac{\partial f_i}{\partial r_k} = 0. \tag{1}$$

Here the constraint functions are embedded using the method of Lagrange Multipliers. The method of Lagrange Multipliers is an optimization technique, used to find local minimas/maximas for an objective function given a set of constraints.

This leads me to believe that the part $ \frac{\partial L}{\partial r_k} - \frac{d}{dt}\frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot{r_k}}$ actually comes from applying the gradient to some objective function. But I can not find any information about this function.

So my question is, is there an objective function here and how can one formulate it? Or is my premise flawed? I would be very thankful for any help or pointers in the right direction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. If the constraints $(f_1,\ldots, f_C)$ are [holonomic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Holonomic_constraints), then OP's Lagrange equations of first kind (1) follows from an extended action principle
   $$ S[r,\lambda]~=~~\int \! dt (L + \sum_{i=1}^C\lambda^i f_i). $$
2. In case of [semi-holonomic](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/283289/2451) constraints or dissipative forces, the situation is more complicated, cf. e.g. [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/283238/2451) & [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/343456/2451) Phys.SE posts.
3. However, within the framework of Newtonian mechanics, the [Lagrange equations of first kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrangian_mechanics) can always be derived from [d'Alembert's principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/D%27Alembert%27s_principle), cf. e.g. H. Goldstein, *Classical mechanics,* chapter 1.