# Lagrangian Mechanics: semi-holonomic constraints

Tags: classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, coordinate-systems, constrained-dynamics

By switching to a different set of coordinates, **can you make problem with semi holonomic constraints into a problem with holonomic constraints?** If so, then *when can you do this*? I wold like to know if this is possible for *all* semi-holonomic problems, *some* semi-holonomic problems or *no* semi-holonomic problems.

My intuition is that it probably works for some specific cases, but not in general. However, I don't know the reason *why*. Would be very nice with some sort of proof.

(Constraints on the form: $f=f(q_i,\dot q_i,t)$.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. A non-holonomic$^1$ constraint is by definition a constraint that is not [holonomic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Holonomic_constraints),
   e.g. on the form $f(q,\dot{q},t)=0$ or an inequality.
2. A semi-holonomic constraint
   $$ \omega~\equiv~\sum_{j=1}^na_j(q,t)~\mathrm{d}q^j+a_0(q,t)\mathrm{d}t~=~0 $$
   is equivalent to a [holonomic constraint](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Holonomic_constraints) iff there exist an integrating factor $\lambda(q,t)\neq 0$ and a one-form $\eta$ such that
   $$ \lambda\omega+ f\eta~\equiv~\mathrm{d}f ,$$
   cf. my related Phys.SE answer [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/410110/2451).

--

$^1$ If you are using the 3rd edition of Goldstein, be aware of [erratum](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/356811/2451).

Comment: I have Pearson New International edition Third edition from 2014. But the last correction made on the errata homepage was in 2010. ( http://astro.physics.sc.edu/Goldstein/ ) I checked one of the revisions ( a $\delta$ corrected to $\partial$) and it was indeed corrected in my edition. Guess it is updated then.

Comment: Eq. (2.26) is still wrong/misleading at best.